# Sharepoint AddIn to azure, error I received -An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again by launching the app installed on your site

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online

I am getting this error when I am deploying a simple SharePoint AddIn to Azure, "An unexpected error has occurred.Please try again by launching the app installed on your site". Kindly help.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?